# Install python2 in 2020

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm currently using python3.9, but I want to try python2.x as well. The problem with me currently, is that the python installation page (https://www.python.org) doesn't download any file whenever I click on [Python 2.7.18](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/). And on all guides I found online, there is supposed to be a download button for python2.x *and* python3.x, but there isn't for me:[image: screenshot] I don't know what I'm supposed to do anymore. Is it still possible to install python 2.x in 2020? If yes, how?

Comment: When I get there, there *is* a link for Python 2.7.18. But like I said, nothing happens when I click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/

Windows x86-64 MSI installer

Windows x86 MSI installer

Comment: Oh, I got it. I thought "Windows x86-64 MSI installer" and "Windows x86 MSI installer" were separate files that come in with python2.7.18 installation. Thanks, I managed to download it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [python's windows releases website](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), and scroll down further, you will be able to clearly see python 2 versions up for download.

Edit: Or you could click on the link at the top for the latest python 2.7.18 download.

Comment: The download link still redirects to https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/. And when I go there, no installation happens.

Comment: @GGberry There is a donwload link on the page? https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18.amd64.msi

Comment: @GGberry there is a download link on the page! be sure to check whether your computer is 64 or 32 bit. Most likely 64 though.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/
here's the link lmk if it worked

Comment: > The download link still redirects to https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/. And when I go there, no installation happens.

Comment: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18.amd64.msi paste this into ur download manager